# How to delete collection type null entries from Database in symfony 4 with sonata admin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata

I want to delete collection entry from database. When I will delete any collection from sonata admin collection then I want to that row deleted from database. But I don't know that. So I need to know that. How can will do it. Please help someone. Thank you.

```
->add('account_person_type', CollectionType::class, [
      'label' => 'Account Person Type',
      'required' => true,
      'by_reference' => false,
      'type_options' => []
      ], ['edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'table', 'sortable' => 'position',]
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete collection null value entries from Database in sonata admin with symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429383/delete-collection-null-value-entries-from-database-in-sonata-admin-with-symfony)

Comment: I dont really understand this question, can you explain it with an example